# how to insert text in the center of an image

Tags: jsf-1.2, jsf-2.2

Could you please tell me to write a text in the middle of an image? I should do it without using div tag.I can succeed doing it by using h:panelGroup or primefaces tag? I created my image by using  tag?

Best Regards
Alper

Comment: `h:panelGroup` is rendered as `div` (or `span`). What is difference if you use `div` or `h:panelGroup`?

Comment: Use image as background for `h:panelGroup`, add text inside, use `style` attribute for centering text (or use `styleClass` and put your styles in css).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center; background-image: url(./images/yourImage.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;">
    <h:outputText value="TEST" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Note 1: Setup proper path in background-image URL, add image size if needed, add vertical align if needed.

Note 2: you can move styles in css and use `styleClass` attribute in `h:panelGroup`.